# AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Where to save files uploaded by the users?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I moved my old web site to AWS.

I have already made several assets working, as:
- My web site shows up under my domain.
- My SQL database is online and it's accessible from my local machine.
- I launched a Linux AMI instance and an Elastic Beanstalk php environment to run my php application, which works too.

Now my php app should occasionally read and write some image files uploaded by my website visitors (by javascript and php scripts).

On my old web hosting it was easy. The php script read/wrote the user's image files within a given directory accessible from my http domain.

On AWS I tried to manually upload an image file on the root of the Elasticbeanstalk Linux bucket (where I found my php app zip files), e.g. "usersimages/image.png" but now if I type http://example.com/usersimages/image.png I get a 404 error.

So, everything works only within the opaque php app, not outside. And I can't include these user's file within the php zip file. The directory "usersimages" contains dynamic data, independent from my php app.

So my question is: where and how to read/write the user's image files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be best the the users' images be uploaded directly to S3. That way it keeps them off your Beanstalk instance and you can easily include the images in your pages. The upload is accomplished using a method called [pre-signed upload URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html). You can create the pre-signed URL in PHP and use the URL in your HTML form to upload the files. An example is [Client side uploads to s3, with pre-signed upload form (PHP/JS)](https://gist.github.com/zxbodya/3cdabd9172bcc89f8ac5).

Comment: Ho can I locally test the method called pre-signed upload URLs? Also, should I zip the whole project and upload/deploy it all the time? How can I edit the php file on the remote server? On my current hosting I use to edit/save the remote php file with Transmit. And I can see the results in seconds. Here I will never end.

Comment: I solved the issue as you said. Thank you. I moved the dynamic files to a new S3 bucket. And I have found the way to point to those public URLs using the AWS method s3://bucketName